# Powershell and .Net. Create new type with string - integer association

Tags: .net, powershell, enums

There are types in .net that can look like different depending on usage. 
2 examples:
1) simple. We have type system.boolean. value of this type can be true, false and 0,1 - that means that boolean can act like integer.
2) close to my need. If we execute (this get last Application log entry and select property that we usually call Severity (Warning, Error, etc.))

```
$a = (Get-EventLog -LogName Application -Newest 1).entrytype
$a | get-member
```

the result is

```
TypeName: System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType
```

This type can be as Integer as String, so

```
$a
Information
$a -gt 1
True
$a -gt 4
False
```

The question: I want to create some type with static mapping "int to string" with same behavior - actually custom log levels.
like `"No log" = 0`, `"Information" = 1`, etc.

Does anyone know how to achieve such thing?

Comment: No, a boolean is never 0 or 1. It's true or false. It doesn't act like an integer, doesn't have mathematical operations. Types don't "look different". There are implicit and explicit *conversions* between types.

Comment: And `entrytype` isn't a boolean. It's an enum. What you confuse for strings are the enumeration's *value names*. There is no mapping. The *underlying* values are integers.

Comment: Check [the documentation for enums](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/enum). Also [New Powershell Feature: Enumerations](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/08/26/new-powershell-5-feature-enumerations/)

Comment: Just to re-iterate on the other suggestions: You are referring to *conversions*.  If you look at the members list of these objects, you can see `ToString()`,`ToInt32()` etc methods on them.  What you want is indeed enumerations.  If you're on PowerShell 5, you can use them natively in scripts.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Enumeration is exactly what I need. second link was very useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So whats going on is a enumeration (enum).

You can see the value of the enum by doing :

```
$a = (Get-EventLog -LogName Application -Newest 1).entrytype
$a.value__
```

You can create your own :

```
enum LogTypes{
    This = 0
    Is = 1
    A = 2
    Enum = 3
    In = 4
    Action = 5
}

[LogTypes]$a = (Get-EventLog -LogName Application -Newest 1).entrytype.value__
$a
```

Enums are useful for forcing a limited number of options and making things easier to read

```
enum LogTypes{
    This = 0
    Is = 1
    A = 2
    Enum = 3
    In = 4
    Action = 5
}
Function TestFunction([LogTypes]$Test){
    Write-Output $Test
}

TestFunction -Test This #Works
TestFunction -Test 3 #Works
TestFunction -Test 11 #Fails
TestFunction -Test Cat #Fails
```

The first 2 would work but the last 2 would fail.

Comment: looks like exactly what  I need. Thanks